# How to use ar_track_alvar for detecting markers using Kinect?

Tags: ros, pcl, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I'm new to ros and want to use it for markers detection. I don't know how to use ar_track_alvar (individualMarkers) in the proper way to make it work using Kinect camera. I'm also confused about the parameters (Camera image topic, Camera topic info, output frame) what should be used there ?

And finally should I run rviz to before using ar_track_alvar package ?

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203207/how-to-use-ar_track_alvar-for-detecting-markers-using-kinect-?/) by [MSYazeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/21653/msyazeed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can indeed use ar_track_alvar to detect ar_markers.

If you are using openni_launch or freenect_launch packages to get the images from your kinect, you should have a bunch of topics published.
Camera image topic stands for the topic where your kinect image is published, should look like: /camera/rgb/image_raw
Camera info topic stands for the topic where the information of your camera are published, shoud look like: /camera/rgb/camera_info 
The output frame parameter means the link relative to which you want the position of the detected ar marjers will be published (for example base_link) or whatever link suits your application. This must be a link known by tf, otherwise ROS won't be able to compute a transformation.
Documentation can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar#Detecting_individual_tags)
Examples can be found [here](https://github.com/sniekum/ar_track_alvar/blob/hydro-devel/launch/pr2_indiv.launch)

The detected markers will be published on /ar_pose_marker (ar_track_alvar/AlvarMarkers) as an array of AlvarMarkers
You can also visualize them in rviz, you just have to add a marker plugin and select the correspondig topic (/visualization_marker).

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MSYazeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/21653/msyazeed/) on 2015-02-24**:
currently I'm using  /camera/rgb/image_color for Camera image topic to make the camera receive the coloured image . and for the output frame I'm using camera_link(not sure its right). but I can't see any output yet and I can't manage to show it on rviz. What am I doing wrong here ?

**Comment by [MSYazeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/21653/msyazeed/) on 2015-02-24**:
I also should note that I ran roscore first then openni_launch then the ar_track_alvar and rviz. it gives me weird error saying '[1424775599.179064296]: Client [/marker_detect] wants topic /camera/rgb/image_color to have datatype/md5sum [~], but our version has [~].  Dropping connection.

**Comment by [MSYazeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/21653/msyazeed/) on 2015-02-24**:
This is the full error: [ERROR] [1424775599.179064296]: Client [/marker_detect] wants topic /camera/rgb/image_color to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181], but our version has [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]. Dropping connection.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-02-25**:
ok, here the error says that this node requires a sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 and not a color image. So you should use depth_registered (camera/depth_registered/image_raw).
If you want to check the type of a message sent on a given topic you can use: `rostopic info TOPICNAME`

**Comment by [MSYazeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/21653/msyazeed/) on 2015-03-02**:
Thank you so much its working now and can detect the the marker, but some how it shows the marker on Rivz for a second then it gives me the following error

**Comment by [MSYazeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/21653/msyazeed/) on 2015-03-02**:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://e

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-03-02**:
No idea, Sorry. I've never face this issue. But it seems that several people got this problem recently: http://answers.ros.org/question/203698/error-while-detecting-markers-using-ar_track_alvar/
Try to track these threads and check on the internet, the solution will pop up in the eventually.

**Comment by [MSYazeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/21653/msyazeed/) on 2015-03-02**:
Thank you so much for your help

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-03-02**:
"will pop up in the NEXT DAYS eventually": forgot some words in the hurry :s

You're welcome, Happy programming !

**Comment by [Leandro](https://answers.ros.org/users/22435/leandro/) on 2015-06-10**:
Thanks for your help! I coudn't make pr2_indiv.launch work but pr2_indiv_no_kinect.launch is running normally thanks to you.